# In Windows Terminal, how do I add bash as one of the shell options?

Tags: windows-10, bash, shell, windows-terminal

I'm using Windows 10 and just downloaded and installed the latest version of Windows Terminal.  I would like to use a bash shell within the terminal but when I open the settings, I don't see bash as an option

[image]

Is it possible to add bash (or something like it) as a selectable shell and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Does [Adding Git-Bash to the new Windows Terminal - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839307/adding-git-bash-to-the-new-windows-terminal) answer your question?

Comment: How have you installed bash? You should be able to click on the "Open a new tab" button in the title-bar and select the Linux distribution that you installed.

Answer (score 1):

Bash, of course, is a shell, but it's just one shell among many that runs in an *operating environment* or *operating system*.

It's that operating environment or operating system that you need to install in order to get access to a Bash shell inside Windows Terminal.  There are multiple options:

- [***Windows Subsystem for Linux***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/):  Allows you to run an actual Linux distribution (the default is Ubuntu) under Windows.  Bash is the default shell for most distributions.

  Windows Terminal will automatically detect any installed WSL distribution and add a profile for it.  Starting the profile for the *WSL distribution* is what will start a Bash shell for you.

  Note that, under WSL, this is a true ELF64 (Linux) binary, and commands you execute in it will typically be Linux commands which understand Linux processes, paths, files, formats, etc.
- ***Git Bash***:  A Bash shell that is installed with [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/downloads).  Designed primarily as a shell for working with Git on Windows at a command-line level.  It is based on [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/), which in turn is based on Cygwin (see below).

  Installing Git for Windows will create a profile for Git Bash in Windows Terminal.
- ***Cygwin***:  The [Cygwin operating environment](https://www.cygwin.com) allows Linux tools to be *ported* to Windows (rather than run natively).  Bash is available for (and typically installed with) Cygwin.

  A Windows Terminal profile is *not* automatically created for Cygwin, but the Terminal docs have [instructions for creating a Cygwin profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles#cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

Add Windows Terminal Profile from its settings page:

Name:
`Git Bash`
Command line:
`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`
Icon:
`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git\git-for-windows.ico`

Git Bash should now open as a tab from the Windows Terminal drop down caret instead of a its own separate window.

Ref: [Adding Git-Bash to Windows Terminal - Tim Schaeps](https://www.timschaeps.be/post/adding-git-bash-to-windows-terminal/)